# Display a pytorch gpu tensor image without copying to cpu memory?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, display

I want to visualize images generated in the gpu with pytorch with as little delay as possible.  Possibly this would involve a 3D rendering context that pytorch could feed tensor images into as textures?  Or do I get this behavior without asking for it with any of these methods https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/auto_examples/plot_visualization_utils.html?

Comment: Trying the same question in the torch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/visualize-tensor-image-without-copying-out-of-gpu/168407

Answer (score 1):

There is python module you can use called Cudacanvas, if you meant with images, like flat images this one does it, you need to install the right version for your pytorch version

for **pytorch with CUDA 12.1**

```
pip install cudacanvas
```

and for **pytorch with CUDA 11.8**

```
pip install cudacanvas --find-links https://github.com/OutofAi/cudacanvas/wiki/cu118
```

and example how you can use it

```
import torch
import cudacanvas


while (True):

    noise_image = torch.rand((4, 500, 500), device="cuda")

    cudacanvas.im_show(noise_image)

    if cudacanvas.should_close():
        #end process if the window is closed
        break
```